# Get time less than "Last Sunday" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get only the time less than "Last Sunday".

The code below only shows the time less than "current date", is there a function for less than "Last Sunday"?

```
SELECT ProjectTitle, TimeByDay
FROM cumulativebyday
Where TimeByDay < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
Order by TimeByDay ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether you're working on mysql or sql-server from your tag.

Here's what you may try in sql-server.

Assuming weekday is returned in English. May also consider using `DATEPART` returning number as the weekday. Again it would be server configuration dependent as weekday could start counting from either Sunday or Monday.

```
SELECT ProjectTitle, TimeByDay
FROM cumulativebyday
Where TimeByDay < 
    DATEADD(DAY, 
        CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  
            WHEN 'Monday' THEN -1
            WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN -2
            WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN -3
            WHEN 'Thursday' THEN -4
            WHEN 'Friday' THEN -5
            WHEN 'Saturday' THEN -6
            WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -7
        END,
        CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ) 
Order by TimeByDay ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has a function called `DayOfWeek(date)`

Get the current day of the week, for example today would return 5. 1 is equal to sunday, so for today we would need to look back at 5-1 days = 4 days. (if the difference is zero we are on a sunday, so we need to go back 7 days to get last sunday)

Using the date_sub (date subtract) and timestamp to convert to a timesstamp, we can get a timestamp of the nearest sunday in the past.  I haven't tested this but it should work. You might want to add one or subtract one if you want to include or exclude records from that sunday.

```
Where TimeByDay < TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), IF(DAYOFWEEK()-1 == 0, 7, DAYOFWEEK()-1))
```